# How to bin timestamp data into buckets of custom width of n hours in vertica

Tags: sql, time-series, vertica

I have a table  which contains a  column Start_Timestamp which has time stamp values like  2020-06-02 21:08:37. I would like to create new column which classifies these timestamps into bins of 6hours.

Eg.

Input :

| Start_Timestamp |
| --- |
| 2020-06-02 21:08:37 |
| 2020-07-19 01:23:40 |
| 2021-11-13 12:08:37 |

Expected Output ( Here each bin is of 6hours width) :

| Start_Timestamp | Bin |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-06-02 21:08:37 | 18H - 24H |
| 2020-07-19 01:23:40 | 00H - 06H |
| 2021-11-13 12:08:37 | 12H - 18H |

I have tried using  TIMESERIES but can anyone help to generate output in following format

Comment: How is "00H-07H" a bin for "six" hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Vertica. Use the `TIME_SLICE()` function. Then, combine it with the `TO_CHAR()` function that Vertica shares with Oracle.

You can always add a `CASE WHEN` expression to change 00:00 to 24:00, but as that is not the standard, I wouldn't even bother.

```
WITH
indata(start_ts) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 21:08:37'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-07-19 01:23:40'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-11-13 12:08:37'
)
SELECT 
  TIME_SLICE(start_ts,6,'HOUR') 
  AS tm_slice
,   TO_CHAR(TIME_SLICE(start_ts,6,'HOUR'),'HH24:MIH - ')
  ||TO_CHAR(TIME_SLICE(start_ts,6,'HOUR','END'),'HH24:MIH') 
  AS caption
, start_ts
FROM indata;
-- out       tm_slice       |     caption     |      start_ts       
-- out ---------------------+-----------------+---------------------
-- out  2020-06-02 18:00:00 | 18:00H - 00:00H | 2020-06-02 21:08:37
-- out  2020-07-19 00:00:00 | 00:00H - 06:00H | 2020-07-19 01:23:40
-- out  2021-11-13 12:00:00 | 12:00H - 18:00H | 2021-11-13 12:08:37
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract the hour and do some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       floor(extract(hour from start_timestamp) / 6) * 6 as bin
from t;
```

Note:  This characterizes the bin by the earliest hour.  That seems more useful than a string representation, but you can construct a string if you really want.